# Image works fine as a HTML <img> but not on CSS background-image What I'm I missing?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm somewhat new to web development (self learning) and I just can't seem to get over the hump of learning how to add background images on CSS.

I added a image on HTML and it shows up fine on the web browser, but when I try to add the same image as a Background Image it's not working. I'm sure I'm missing something simple but so far I cant figure it out. Here is the code

This is my HTML img code that works perfectly fine

```
<div class="pic"
<img src="C:\Users\omar\Pictures/applelogoretro.jpg.jpg" atl="happy"
style="width:85%; height:75%;"/>
</div>
```

Background image HTML

```
<div class="backpic">
<p>This is the TEXT on my BackGround image</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.backpic{
background-image: url"C:\Users\omar\Pictures/applelogoretro.jpg.jpg";
}
```

Why does the image work fine as a regular image, but not as a background image. The more detail your answer the more it will help me, thanks in advance to all!

Comment: You shouldn't use local absolute path for your images. Use relative paths instead. Also, the syntax of CSS background-image is incorrect. Do not make up your own syntax.

Comment: As pointed out by Raptor, look up what relative paths are, they will save you a ton of work.

Answer (score 3):

Url in css should be inside parenthesis:

So this line 
`background-image: url"C:\Users\omar\Pictures/applelogoretro.jpg.jpg";`

Should be `background-image: url("C:\Users\omar\Pictures/applelogoretro.jpg.jpg");`

*As @Raptor and @YAHsaves pointed out, you should use relative paths*

Answer (score 2):

May be try checking syntax, see if this will do it?

```
background-image: url("pathtoyourimage.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the syntax  error(>), see if it will do this

```
     .pic{ background-image: url(ggg.jpg);  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```